# Generate report that shows how each condition in a SQL CLAUSE effects the total rows outputted by the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, report, business-intelligence

For example, I'm trying to view how each condition in the below SQL will affect the total rows outputted.

```
SELECT * FROM   {Tables..}  WHERE date > '2017' 
   AND ( location = 'US' 
          OR location = 'CA' 
          OR location = 'MX' ) 
   AND customer_order > 1 
   AND latest_cust_order_tot >= 1000
```

The ideal output would be [image: similar to this image] or the below output:

```
    Criteria Desc.                 SQL Code                                           Rows Removed    Records Remaining
    Total Purchases YTD            DATE > '2017'                                                     0             100020
    Customers from the North AmericLOCATION = 'US' OR LOCATION = 'CA' or LOCATION = 'M           44500              55520
    Repeat Customers               CUSTOMER_ORDER > 1                                            20300              35220
    Most recent order over $500    LATEST_CUST_ORDER_TOT >= 1000                                 33810               1410
```

Trying to solve it with BI tools or just SQL. I'm not looking to hardcode a query to produce the results as the conditions can range to more then 50 and will change based on user input.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL-server

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       SUM(CASE WHEN date > '2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as condition_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date > '2017' AND location IN ('US', 'CA', 'MX') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as condition_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date > '2017' AND location IN ('US', 'CA', 'MX') AND customer_order > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as condition_3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date > '2017' AND location IN ('US', 'CA', 'MX') AND customer_order > 1 AND latest_cust_order_tot >= 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as condition_3,
FROM   {Tables..}  ;
```

This puts the counts in separate columns.

Comment: Yes that will generate the desired output. Sorry I should have been more specific. Is there more of an automated/dynamic way. I just simplified the example but in reality there could 50+ filters that changed based on user input.. Thanks for providing an answer :)

Comment: Would it work to create a stored procedure that can accept a SQL Statement as a parm then parse out the conditions and create a new query similar to what you have done above?

Comment: @user2548089 . . . Parsing SQL statements is really complicated.